# Prove that an integer which divides $p^t$ must equal $p^k$ for some k, $1\leq k\leq t$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let *p* be a prime number and *t* a positive number. Let $a\in\mathbf Z$. Suppose that *a* divides $p^t$. Prove that $a=p^k$ for some $k\in\mathbf Z$, $1\leq k\leq t$.

I feel like this question should be easy, but so far, all I've gotten is that $p^t$=*an* for some *n*. I'm assuming that I need to write $p^t$ in some sort of factorized form of *p*, but I'm not really sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it'd help more to write $a$ in some sort of factorized form, because $p^t$ is pretty much already factorized.

Comment: What about the possibility that $a$ is negative?

Comment: $k=0$ works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: List all the factors of $p^t$ and note that $a$ must be a factor of $p^t$ and so is somewhere on that list

Comment: Wouldn't the factors just be 1,_p_, and $p^k$ for some _k_ less than _t_?

Comment: @C.Thomson Exactly

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, we can assume that $a>0$.

If $a=1$, then $a=p^0$.

If $a>1$, let $q$ be a prime factor of $a$. Then $q$ divides $p^t$ and so $q=p$. (If a prime divides a product then it divides one of the factors.) So, $p$ is the only prime factor of $a$ and therefore $a=p^k$ with $k \le t$ because $a \le p^t$.